# How to generate and download pdf with dynamic image path from database using any npm packages

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pdf, npm

I'm building a software using express-mongodb-ejs. I've tried some of the npm packages to generate and download pdf. But, I cant generate pdf which having the dynamic image path.

I've used html-pdf package, which seems pretty good. But, It can't render the dynamic image path from database.
[Here is the screenshot where I used the html-pdf package.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io1Jg.png)

[Here is the detailed problem link where I asked about this package related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64105166/image-is-not-rendering-from-dynamic-image-path-while-using-express-html-pdf-pack)

Can anyone provide me any detailed solution regarding the problem? Any npm package should be fine as long as it can help me to download pdf using express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a popular node module called `pdfkit`. Please run the below program and check it. You need an image with the name `pro.jpg` in the same folder that you run the script. It will generate an `output.pdf` file.

Here is the example:

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const fs = require('fs');

// Create a document
const doc = new PDFDocument();

// Pipe its output somewhere, like to a file or HTTP response
// See below for browser usage
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));

// Add an image, constrain it to a given size, and center it vertically and horizontally
doc.image('pro.jpg', {
  fit: [250, 300],
  align: 'center',
  valign: 'center'
});

// Add another page
doc
  .addPage()
  .fontSize(25)
  .text('Here is some vector graphics...', 100, 100);

// Draw a triangle
doc
  .save()
  .moveTo(100, 150)
  .lineTo(100, 250)
  .lineTo(200, 250)
  .fill('#FF3300');

// Apply some transforms and render an SVG path with the 'even-odd' fill rule
doc
  .scale(0.6)
  .translate(470, -380)
  .path('M 250,75 L 323,301 131,161 369,161 177,301 z')
  .fill('red', 'even-odd')
  .restore();

// Add some text with annotations
doc
  .addPage()
  .fillColor('blue')
  .text('Here is a link!', 100, 100)
  .underline(100, 100, 160, 27, { color: '#0000FF' })
  .link(100, 100, 160, 27, 'http://google.com/');

// Finalize PDF file
doc.end();
```