# pdfkit library is not embedding images in the pdf file generated

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit

I am using PDFkit with node.js to convert an html page to pdf. HTML page has several image tags in body tag.

However When I convert html to pdf I get the black page generated. Can someone help me with the issue? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@simran I hope this answer solves your issue. Try this logic it works for me:
I just posted it on another thread for pdf related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64114358/3202440